# Are all namekians brothers?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

IIRC , all namekians were born from the grand elder, but apparently in the new chapter of the Dragon Ball Super manga they say

> One character who heals Goku and Vegeta is Dende's brother. If he's Dende's brother, does this mean the other namekians arent his brothers?

Then, are all namekians brothers or not?

Answer (score 3):

There was a [population bottleneck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_bottleneck) due to an [ecological crisis in Namek's history](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Namek#Climate_shift), so most remaining Namekians originate from a single Namekian, [Grand Elder Guru](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Elder_Guru). So most Namekians are brothers.

There were a few Namekians who were sent away from the planet prior to the climate shift though, and so these Namekians would be further apart on the family tree. Among those who survived, there was most notably the child of Katas, the Namekian who later split himself into King Piccolo and Earth's Kami.

Some highlights of the [Namekian family tree](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Family_trees#Katas_and_King_Piccolo.27s_family_tree) are as follows:

- Katas had the Nameless Namekian.

  - The Nameless Namekian split into King Piccolo and Kami.

    - Kami created Shenlong, the dragon for the Earth Dragon Balls.
    - King Piccolo had Drum, Tambourine, Cymbal, Piano, Piccolo Jr, and a bunch of other offspring.

      - Piccolo Jr fused with Nail, and then after that, Kami.
- Grand Elder Guru had Nail, Moori, Dende, Cargo, and 105 other Namekians. He also created Porunga, the dragon for the Namekian Dragon Balls.

  - Nail fused with Piccolo Jr.
  - Dende resurrected Shenlong.